# How to access Configuration file in Class library from webpage as well as webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, winforms, webforms

I have several projects some of which are web applications and some are windows applications.
I wanted to globalize my settings, something like Connection Strings because all the projects use the same connection string.
So I followed this example [How to share custom application configuration settings across projects in .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555396)

my XML file is in the  class library and that is referenced in each project. The windows project are working fine with the file path which is something like this in the client project:

```
<configuration>
      <appSettings file="F:\Classes\ConnectionStringFile.xml">

      </appSettings>

    </configuration>
```

I also want to be able to use this xml file from a web project. however, the web project would not accept the path to this file as shown earlier.

What is the best approach or say, best solution to have this connection string file shared amongst web projects as well as windows projects. What do i pass in

something like `<appSettings file ="~/classLibrary/ConnectionStringFile.xml"` ???`

Comment: Obviously the client and web projects aren't deployed on the same computer.  The web project will be deployed differently.  The file= attribute uses relative paths, and for the web project the path should be a relative local path.  If that isn't sufficient you should give more detail on the context of the web server.

Answer (score 0):

The solution we use is to store shared settings in a custom folder beneath the CommonApplicationData folder (e.g. C:\ProgramData on Windows7):

```
var commonAppData = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);
var settingsFilePath = Path.Combine(commonAppData, "MyProgram\\Settings.xml");
```

Comment: I want this file to be accessed both from web project as well as windows project. this file contains connection strings that means that the class library (that contains all the classes) will have to use this connection string (from this file). on development machine, the windows application can access the file path i.e. "f:\classes\ConnectionStringFile.xml" however, the web form needs something like "~\something\ConnectionStringFile.xml". How can I do this so that both web and win projects can access this file from the class library?

Answer (score 0):

`file=` accepts relative paths, and *.config files are excluded from ASP.NET and IIS static file rules, so it is safe to drop any *.config file into an ASP.NET site.  Just put it next to the web.config file (root of the web app), `mylibrary.config`, and `file="mylibrary.config"`.

Comment: I want this file to be accessed both from web project as well as windows project. this file contains connection strings that means that the class library (that contains all the classes) will have to use this connection string (from this file). on development machine, the windows application can access the file path i.e. "f:\classes\ConnectionStringFile.xml" however, the web form needs something like "~\something\ConnectionStringFile.xml". How can I do this so that both web and win projects can access this file from the class library?

Comment: based on your suggested answer, if i place this config file next to web.config, it means this config file will be hosted on the web project. where as i have this config file in the class library referenced in the web project. and also, if i do so, how would i be able to access it from the windows application?

Comment: web.config file= attribute doesn't take virtual paths (like ~/dir/file.config), it takes local filesystem paths (like f:\dir\file.config), so if you want to use absolute paths that is fine, as long as the worker process running web app has ACL/NTFS permission to access that path.